Aiding and abetting indirectly/where the principal is not the person intended by D (English Law)
If X encourages Y to commit crime A, but, rather than commit the crime himself (and unknown to X), Y then encourages a third party Z to commit crime A.

X could be charged with inchoate liability for crime A under SCA 2007 s44, as it is X's intention that matters, rather than whether the crime was actually committed.
However, could X also be charged as an accessory/secondary party to crime A, given that crime A was actually committed? The issue I am not clear on is how this would work given that X has not directly encouraged Z to commit crime A. Would causation be an issue here?

Many thanks for any ideas.

canada
I know you have asked about England and Wales, but I provide an answer from Canada for a comparative perspective and to highlight the importance of the particular statutory regime.
Party liability through aiding or abetting requires the aid or abettment to assist the person who actually commits the offence.
But while your title asks about aiding and abetting, your question text asks about the separate path to party liability called "counselling."
The counsellor becomes a party even if the person being counselled is only a party to (as opposed to having actually committed) the offence.
